# What is a difference between importing global styles in angular-cli.json and adding them separately to every css in every component?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-cli, angular5

I have in styles in angular-cli.json `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`. Why when I remove these lines and I add to every css in every component `@import "{correct path to every directory/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css}"`it doesn't work as before?

Answer (score 3):

The styles from `styles.scss` or included in the `angular-cli.json` work globally on the page, whereas when imported - they work only for the specific component.

That being said, it's probably not working for you, because bootstrap adds some styles to i.e. `<html>` or `<body>` elements and your components cannot style these.

Most likely your `AppComponent`'s locator (`app-root` or so) is placed inside `<body>`. It cannot style parents.

Comment: So let's assume that I have two angular projects with in both global styles added to angular-cli.json. I thought about adding in one project these imported in angular-cli.json styles to all components and then add this whole project to another one. Project with css in angular-cli.json would be work properly because we wouldn't change anything and the second also would work properly because styles in css in components would override global styles. But it doesn't as you described it. Any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your use case, but importing bootstrap in the components is just a bad idea as their styles are encapsulated.

Comment: In one project I have imported `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` in the second one `"./assets/css/bootstrap.min.css"`. Unfortunately both works only with own `bootstrap.min.css` declared globally in angular-cli.json. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: `angular-cli.json` is where they should be, nothing wrong about it. I don't know how you would like to combine your two projects, but to share some parts of them, I think you could just use angular modules and / or angular library packages if really needed.

Comment: What do you think about including two apps in one Angular project. First would be landing page with login and registration and the second one would be main panel of the app? Then I could have two angular-cli and there wouldn't be any problem. But the question is whether it is a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap should be imported once in your global stylesheet, then bootstrap classes/components may be used in your entire application.

Styles imported in component decorators are encapsulated (by default) and should be used inside given component only. When you try to import Bootstrap to all your components, generated stylesheet is repeated many times.